# WooCommerce template styles defined in email-styles not adding to template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, sendinblue

As the questions suggests, is there anything that would prevent the styles defined in email-styles.php being added into the email templates?

I'm using the sendinblue API.

I've manually added styles into the template to test and that works, so it's not a case of styles being ripped out or similar.

The emails are sent completely style less, not even the standard WooCommerce styles are present.

Thanks.